# How do I run Node.js server with Socket.io in Apache using ProxyPass?

Tags: node.js, apache, websocket, socket.io, proxypass

I'm trying to set up Socket.io connection in Apache using Node.js via `ProxyPass`. The server works just fine and returns data upon `fetch`, but Socket.io fails to connect for some reason. I tried setting different `path` option within Socket.io but that didn't work either.

**httpd.conf**

```
<VirtualHost 123.45.789:8005>
   <Location "/node">
      ProxyPass http://localhost:5555/
   </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

**Server**

```
// Bunch of require() statements..

const server = http.createServer(app);

const io = require('socket.io')(server.listen(5555), {
   path: '/' // Tried '/node', 'node', '/node/'
});

io.on('connection', socket => {
   console.log('CONNECTED!') // This never logs obviously.
});
```

**Client**

```
import { io } from "socket.io-client";

const uri = 'http://123.45.789:8005';
// const uri = 'http://123.45.789:8005/node';
// const uri = 'http://123.45.789:8005/node/';
// const uri = 'http://123.45.789:8005/node/socket.io';
// const uri = 'http://123.45.789:8005/node/socket.io/';

const socket = io({
   path: uri,
   rejectUnauthorized: false,
});

socket.on('connect', () => console.log('CONNECTED!')); // Never logs either.
```

**Console Error**

```
GET http://10.***.***.***:8080/socketjs-node/info?t=1639773280240 net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

I'm totally lost.. any help would be great, thanks.